# how to make a case-insensitive graphql query?

Tags: graphql

Using GraphQL to fetch and parse a config file, sometimes the file name be `podfile`, sometimes be `Podfile`, so I am wondering how to make a case-insensitive query?

now I only can query repository->object: podfile and Podfile, but if the file name be `podFILE`, again not works.

```
query($org_name: String!, $resp_name: String!)
                {
                repository(owner: $org_name name: $resp_name){
                          object: object(expression: "%s:proj.ios_mac/podfile"){
                                                              ... on Blob{
                                                                          text
                                                                          }
                                                              }
                          ios_object_1: object(expression: "%s:proj.ios_mac/Podfile"){
                                                              ... on Blob{
                                                                          text
                                                                          }
                                                              }
                          }
                }
```

REF:https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/graphql-api-resource-query-is-case-sensitive/m-p/6003

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `_ilike` operator makes the query case-insensitive.

```
query MyQuery {
  heroes(where: {name: {_ilike: "%baTmaN%"}}) {name, movie }
}
```

Source & documentation: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/1516

Answer (score 4):

```
_similar: "%key%" performs Case sensitive query
_ilike:   "%key%" performs case insensitive query
```

For Eg : Below query will return all devices with name contains iphone. It fails to return objects if name contains "iPhone" i.e. the query is case sensitive.

```
query MyQuery {
  devices: devices(where: {name: { _similar: "%iphone%"}}) {
    name
 }
}
```

Below query will return all objects with name containing "iphone", "IPhone". i.e. case insensitive

```
query MyQuery {
  devices: devices(where: {name: { _ilike: "%iphone%"}}) {
    name
 }
}
```

Comment: please add bit of elaboration, it will help understand it clearly.

Comment: @MobileEvangelist have elaborated

Comment: _ilike this answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Names in GraphQL are case-sensitive, as per the [spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Names). Names include field names, type names, variable names etc.

So, in short it is not possible to do it.

Comment: The spec url doesn't work anymore, here is the update for 2019: https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Names

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using [Primsa](https://www.prisma.io) with PostgreSQL, you need to set the `mode` property to `insensitive`, e.g.

```
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
  where: {
    email: {
      endsWith: 'prisma.io',
      mode: 'insensitive'
    },
  },
})
```

[Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/case-sensitivity#postgresql-provider).

Answer (score -1):

There's an abbreviated way of writing the _ilike operator now.

For matching a string with insensitive case you can use eqi.

```
query MyQuery {
  posts (
    filters: { name : { eqi: "my post"}}
  ) { ... }
}
```

Or for querying a string that contains the same value with insensitive case you can use containsi.

```
query MyQuery {
  posts (
    filters: { name : { containsi: "my "}}
  ) { ... }
}
```